# IntelliJ - how to prevent from adding an empty space when pasting entire lines?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, code-formatting

Having a multicursor turned on:

[image]

When I use copy/cut (latter, in this example) shortcut, without any lines selected (just with the blinking cursor), I copy/cut the entire lines. After hitting `Ctrl+X` and `Ctrl+V` in another method:

[image]

One can notice that there are empty spaces after every pasted line.

**Question:** How can I prevent it and make it look like in the picture below?

[image]

**NOTE:** I occurred the same problem when pasting a single line, but it can be prevented easily by putting a coursor at the beginning of the next, already filled with something, line (`var1++;` line copied already):

[image]

And after hitting `Ctrl+C`:

[image]

Unfortunately - it does not work in a multicursor mode.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an easy solution for what you want, we can improve the logic to not add the additional `\n` if the selection already contains `\n`, request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

well if you copied all three lines and are pasting them to one spot you only need a single cursor in the target not multiple. (unless of course these are being pasted as a replacement amidst three other lines)